# Cannot create a mysql view from other views

Tags: mysql, view, mysql-error-1064, mariadb

I have the following views

M_VWPROC_sub1,M_VWPROC_sub2,M_VWPROC_sub3,M_VWPROC_sub4,M_VWPROC_sub5,
M_VWPROC_sub6,M_VWPROC_sub7,M_VWPROC_sub8,M_VWPROC_sub9

I tried to create a view using the following sql.but I get the following error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'M_VWPROC_sub2 union all M_VWPROC_sub3 union all M_VWPROC_sub4
>   union all M_VWPROC' at line 2

Query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  VIEW M_VWPROC (UNIT, PS_DATE, LOCALIN, STOCKIN, STOCKOUT) AS 
select inner_sub_table.UNIT, 
       inner_sub_table.PS_DATE, 
       sum(inner_sub_table.LOCALIN)LOCALIN, 
       sum(inner_sub_table.pur) STOCKIN, 
       sum(inner_sub_table.sale) STOCKOUT 
  from M_VWPROC_sub1 
 union all M_VWPROC_sub2 
 union all M_VWPROC_sub3 
 union all M_VWPROC_sub4 
 union all M_VWPROC_sub5
 union all M_VWPROC_sub6 
 union all M_VWPROC_sub7 
 union all M_VWPROC_sub8 
 union all M_VWPROC_sub9) 
       inner_sub_table
 group by inner_sub_table.UNIT, inner_sub_table.PS_DATE;
```

Any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for `union all` requires a subquery . . . that is a `select` clause.  But, you cannot do what you want.  You need another layer of subqueries.  Something like:

```
create view v_YetAnotherView as 
 select * from M_VWPROC_sub1 
 union all select * from M_VWPROC_sub2 
 union all select * from M_VWPROC_sub3 
 union all select * from M_VWPROC_sub4 
 union all select * from M_VWPROC_sub5
 union all select * from M_VWPROC_sub6 
 union all select * from M_VWPROC_sub7 
 union all select * from M_VWPROC_sub8 
 union all select * from M_VWPROC_sub9;
```

And then:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  VIEW M_VWPROC (UNIT, PS_DATE, LOCALIN, STOCKIN, STOCKOUT) AS 
select inner_sub_table.UNIT, 
       inner_sub_table.PS_DATE, 
       sum(yav.LOCALIN)LOCALIN, 
       sum(yav.pur) STOCKIN, 
       sum(yav.sale) STOCKOUT 
  from YetAnotherView yav
  group by yav.UNIT, yav.PS_DATE;
```

Do note that this ridiculous limitation on views (that the `from` clause cannot contain subqueries) is limited to MySQL.

Comment: I did not understand what Ravinder said,Can you explain.? Also the second query fails. I get the error ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'db_milma.YetAnotherView' doesn't exist
Also the second query should be CREATE OR REPLACE  VIEW M_VWPROC (UNIT, PS_DATE, LOCALIN, STOCKIN, STOCKOUT) AS 
select yav.UNIT, 
       yav.PS_DATE, 
       sum(yav.LOCALIN)LOCALIN, 
       sum(yav.pur) STOCKIN, 
       sum(yav.sale) STOCKOUT 
  from YetAnotherView yav
  group by yav.UNIT, yav.PS_DATE;